# Gradle dependency without version

Tags: gradle, nexus, sonatype

I am migrating a larger project to Gradle and I have a problem migrating one of the dependencies.

Previously we had all of our dependencies locally in a lib folder right inside the project.
We now shifted to retrieving them the Gradle way via MavenCentral and other repositories. Some of the libraries that we use cannot be retrieved from any public repository. Therefore we set up an internal repository (Sontype Nexus) and uploaded the libraries manually.

Now, there is one library for which this does not work. I'll refer to that library as SAMPLE. The issue is, that the library checks the classpath at runtime and looks for itself. Problem is, that the library only looks for a "SAMPLE.jar". But because of the Repository-restrictions the jar is now called "SAMPLE-{version}.jar". Therefore the library fails at runtime with an exception.

I have already managed to "deploy" the jar to Nexus without a version number via HTTP PUT. But now I can't declare a dependency inside Gradle as I am obligated to specify a version.

Is there any workaround to this situation that does not include changing the library?

Comment: I also considered using a local file dependency. Downside is, that the project in question is itself used as a dependency by other projects. And local file dependencies cannot be automatically be resolved. Or is there a way that they can be?

Comment: Have you tried to include the local file dependency (SAMPLE.jar) inside the result.jar? Like a fat-jar / uber-jar?

Comment: Uber-JAR would've been one way of going about it. My current solution is that I download the file automatically and then declare a file dependency on it.